# MPMoviePlayerController is functioning wrong

Tags: ios, url, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

When i tried a video saved on the Xcode project , it worked.
then when i changed it with a url , it always returns this error :

```
 _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
```

}

Here's my code :

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9MNAeGWd_04"];

movieController = [[MoviePlayerVC alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
movieController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[movieController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];

[movieController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[[movieController view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
[self presentViewController:movieController animated:NO completion:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:)
                                             name:@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

`fileURLWithPath:` expects a local path url - `/User/blah/blah.mp3`

Try to use `[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9MNAeGWd_04"]`

Comment: actually quellish is correct, you can't play youtube videos in MPMoviePlayer... check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview for reference

Answer (score 1):

IF YOU PLAY FROM URL THEN TRY THIS

```
-(void)playFromLiveUrl
{

        NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"*YOUR URL*"];
        _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:aUrl];
        _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        _moviePlayer.view.frame = asyvideoImage.frame;
        _moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
        [self.view addsubview _moviePlayer.view];
        [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];

}
```

IF YOU ARE USE LOCAL FILE THEN USE THIS

```
-(void)playFromLocal
{

        _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"** LOCAL PATH ** "]];
        _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        _moviePlayer.view.frame = asyvideoImage.frame;
        _moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
        [self.view addsubview _moviePlayer.view];
        [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: it open black screen only.

Comment: yes i added this URL "https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9MNAeGWd_04"and i changed the "asyvideoImage.frame" to CGRectmake(0,0,320,548)

Comment: if you want to play video from the youtube URL then you have to find some custom class to play video from youtube URL

Comment: Actually its a url from sever , but i replaced it with youtube as i found that no urls are working with the code :(

Comment: please check the below link you can get something from that 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview    2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911171/mpmovieplayercontroller-is-playing-youtube-video

Answer (score 1):

The `MPMoviewPlayerController` Can't get your format. U r try to load the `MPMoviePlayerController` with youTube link, it won't work (as u can see :)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535836/video-file-formats-supported-in-iphone) u can find the iPhone video format support.

Try to load your `MoviePlayer` something like this (for example `.m3u8` format):

```
[movieController setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerController` cannot play a Flash Youtube URL. Use a web view instead. UIWebView on iOS is smart enough play youtube content.

You can see the video formats `MPMoviePlayer` and `AVFoundation` support [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html)